# Django Update data using getlist

Tags: django

How do i update every **students marking**?

this is my admin site
[image]

i distinct the student name

this my views.py

```
    //I distinct duplicate student name
    student = StudentsBehaviorGrades.objects.filter(Teacher = teacher).filter(Grading_Period = coreperiod).values\
        ('Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname','Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname','id')\
    .distinct('Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname','Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname')\
    .order_by('Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname','Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname')

    //I display the marking of students mark (selection box) this is correct
    studentsbehaviorgrade = StudentsBehaviorGrades.objects.filter(Teacher=teacher).filter(Grading_Period=coreperiod).order_by('Grading_Behavior__Display_Sequence')
```

this is my html

```
{% for students in student %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" value="{{students.id}}" name="id">{{students.Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname}} {{students.Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname}}</td>
            {% for be in studentsbehaviorgrade %}
            <td colspan="4">
                 <select name="Marking">
                     <option value="{{be.Marking.id}}">{{be.Marking}}</option>
                     {% for behaviors in behavior %}
                     <option value="{{behaviors.id}}">{{behaviors.Marking}}</option>
                     {% endfor %}
                 </select>
             </td>
            {% endfor %}

        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

and this is the result

[image]

this is my logic on update.

```
marks=[]
for mark in request.POST.getlist('Marking'):
    marks.append(mark)
    print(marks)

for s, student in enumerate(request.POST.getlist('Marking')):
    studentgrade = marks[s]
    print(studentgrade)
    psa = StudentBehaviorMarking(id=studentgrade)
    update = StudentsBehaviorGrades.objects.get(Marking = student)

    update.Marking=psa
    update.save()
    return render(request, 'Homepage/pending.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
{% for students in student %}
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" value="{{students.id}}" >{{students.Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Lastname}} {{students.Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Students_Enrollment_Records__Student_Users__Firstname}}</td>
            {% for corevalues in studentsbehaviorgrade %}
            <td colspan="4">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="id">
                 <select name="Marking">
                     <option value="{{corevalues.Marking.id}}" >{{corevalues.Marking.id}}-{{corevalues.Marking.Marking}}</option>
                     {% for behaviors in behavior %}
                        <option value="{{behaviors.id}}">{{behaviors.id}}-{{behaviors.Marking}}</option>
                     {% endfor %}
                 </select>
             </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

and copy this in your logic in update

```
marks=[]
    for mark in request.POST.getlist('Marking'):
        marks.append(mark)
        #print(marks)
    corevalues = []
    for corevaluesid in request.POST.getlist('coredescription'):
        corevalues.append(corevaluesid)
    for i, student in enumerate(request.POST.getlist('id')):
        marked =marks[i]
        psa = StudentBehaviorMarking(id=marked)
        update = StudentsBehaviorGrades.objects.get(id=student)
        update.Marking = psa
        update.save()
```