# How to insert the proper value of every students, selecting every mark for every corevalues

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60585371/django-insert-getlist-data). I just don't know how to get the correct data.

Just like in this picture
(for every student, selecting every mark for every corevalues **(is Demonstrate pride …..)**):

[image]

This is my views.py:

```
for i, mark in enumerate(request.POST.getlist('Marking')):
    p = marking[int(mark)]
    s = StudentBehaviorMarking(id=p)
    core = corevalues[i]
    cores = EducationLevelGradingBehavior(id=core)
    print(s, cores)
    for student in  request.POST.getlist('student'):
        students = StudentPeriodSummary(id=student)
        V_insert_data = StudentsBehaviorGrades(
                Teacher=teacher,
                #Education_Levels
                Students_Enrollment_Records = students,
                Grading_Period = coreperiod,
                Grading_Behavior = cores,
                Marking = s,

            )
        V_insert_data.save()
```

And my HTML:

```html
<tr>
    {% for corevalues in behaviorperlevels %}
        <td colspan="4" style="font-size: 12px"><input type="text" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="coredescription">{{corevalues.Grading_Behavior.GroupName}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="2">Student name</td>
    {% for corevalues in behaviorperlevels %}
        <td colspan="4" style="font-size: 12px"><input type="text" value="{{corevalues.id}}" name="period">Q {{corevalues.Grading_Period.id}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% for student in Students %}
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" value="{{student.id}}" name="student">{{student.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users}}</td>
    {% for corevalues in behaviorperlevels %}
    <td colspan="4">
         <select name="Marking">
             {% for behaviors in behavior %}
             <option value="{{behaviors.id}}">{{behaviors.Marking}}</option>
             {% endfor %}
         </select>
     </td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This is my models.py:

```
class GradingBehavior(models.Model):
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    GroupName = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    GroupDescription = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

//this is models corevalues
class EducationLevelGradingBehavior(models.Model):
    Display_Sequence = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    GradeLevel = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                   null=True, blank=True)
    Grading_Behavior = models.ForeignKey(GradingBehavior, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Grading_Period = models.ForeignKey(gradingPeriod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

//this is the models where the user selecting the marks for every core values
class StudentBehaviorMarking(models.Model):
    Marking = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    Non_numerical_Rating = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

//this is the model where the data saves
class StudentsBehaviorGrades(models.Model):
    Teacher = models.ForeignKey(EmployeeUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True, blank=True)
    Education_Levels = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Students_Enrollment_Records = models.ForeignKey(StudentPeriodSummary, 
                                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    Grading_Period = models.ForeignKey(gradingPeriod, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Grading_Behavior = models.ForeignKey(EducationLevelGradingBehavior, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    Marking = models.ForeignKey(StudentBehaviorMarking,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

When I try to insert data

[image]

this is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the data I inserted is not matching properly, I didn't get the right value of every **students mark** for every **corevalues**.

Comment: Why are you placing `coredescription` and `Marking` into a list at all? You're using them "as is" right after filling the lists. Why not just use unzipped values as is? `marking[int(i)]` - no, treating a value as a key is not a great idea. The key here is index of a value in the list.

Comment: How sir? please show me your solution.

Comment: Have you heard of Django forms and formsets?

Comment: @CarlBrubaker is it related to my problem sir?

Comment: It just seems like using a modelForm would make a lot of sense for this. Maybe I'm just not understanding your code

Comment: @CarlBrubaker I am selecting a marked(selection box) for every student and every core values then sending all data back to the database

Comment: Sounds like a modelForm to me

Comment: please check my update question.

Comment: how do I do this in modelForm @CarlBrubaker

Comment: [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209508/discussion-between-mary-and-carl-brubaker).

Comment: @CarlBrubaker can you please provide example using my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your views.py

```
marking = []
for markingID in request.POST.getlist('Marking'):
    marking.append(markingID)

for i, mark in enumerate(request.POST.getlist('Marking')):
    s = StudentBehaviorMarking(id=mark)
    core = corevalues[i]
    cores = EducationLevelGradingBehavior(id=core)
    print("mark", mark, "per description", core)
    for student in request.POST.getlist('student'):
        students = StudentPeriodSummary(id=student)
        V_insert_data = StudentsBehaviorGrades(
            Teacher=teacher,
            Students_Enrollment_Records=students,
            Grading_Period=coreperiod,
            Grading_Behavior=cores,
            Marking=s,
        )
        V_insert_data.save()
```

and do this in your html

```
    {% for student in Students %}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" value="{{student.id}}" name="student">{{student.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Students_Enrollment_Records.Student_Users}}</td>
        {% for corevalues in behaviorperlevels %}
        <td colspan="4">{{corevalues.id}}{{student.id}}
             <select name="Marking">
                 {% for behaviors in behavior %}
                 <option value="{{behaviors.id}}">{{behaviors.id}}-{{behaviors.Marking}}</option>
                 {% endfor %}
             </select>
         </td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```